# Logging from within WSO2 custom mediator

Tags: log4j, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to be able to log from within a custom mediator that I have built.

A few questions:

1. What do I need to add to the esb's log4.properties to enable a custom class the ability to write to log files?
2. From within the custom mediator class, do I need declare the following to log to the synapse log file?

   `private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(<ClassName>.class);`

I have seen many examples of using the log mediator, but I need to be able to control more of what I log from within mediator class.

Answer (score 6):

By default your custom mediator logs will be sent to Carbon Log file as well as Carbon Memory and the console. And also you do not need to define 
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(.class);
again in your class, you can simply use the log object which is coming from AbstractMediator

Please refer the [following guide](http://wso2.com/library/2936/) which explains how to write your custom mediator as well as how you should log inside a mediator.

You can change the level of the log by editing the log4j.properties file or by going to configure -> logging using the management console to get more control on what to log and what not to log.

Comment: Awesome answer. You've just made my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can add the mediator class to log4j.properties

log4j.logger.org.foo.bar=ERROR, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY

Regards,
/Nuwan